# Force.com IDE Issues

Tags: force.com, eclipse

I am downloaded from force.com IDE software from the following site.,
[Force.com IDE](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation)

In my system is Windows7: 32 bit, So I downloaded [Windows Installer (32-bit)](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation)
and I tried to install into my ststem, It is installed but I got the following error.[image: error]

I am using JVM7.

I am already having eclipse force.com IDE in my system, I that Its working fine for my developer edition but its not working for sandbox, I have a admin privileges in my sandbox account. but still its not working.here is the error,

[image: force.com IDE error]

Because of this error only I will go for the new Force.com IDE installation.

Any ideas?

Comment: what was the error?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to your JVM 7, if I recall correctly, on my windows box I had to install JVM 6, and point my global variables to the bin dirs in order to get Force.com IDE working.

> **Steps**
>
> Step 1 : Right Click on MyComputer and click on properties .
>
> Step 2 : Click on Advanced tab
>
> Step 3 : Click on Environment Variables
>
> Step 4: Create a new class path for JAVA_HOME
>
> Step 5: Enter the Variable name as JAVA_HOME and the value to your jdk
>   bin path ie c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.6\bin and
>
> NOTE Make sure u start with ; in the Value so that it doesn't corrupt
>   the other environment variables which is already set.
>
> Step 6 : Follow the Above step and edit the Path in System Variables
>   add the following ;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.6\bin in the value
>   column.
>
> Step 7 :Your are done setting up your environment variables for your
>   Java , In order to test it go to command prompt and type
>
> ```
>  java -version
> ```
>
> which will give you the version of java (should be 1.6)

Comment: but my java version is 1.7.0

Comment: you should be able to install both java versions in parallel on your machine without any problem. There are some answers in this question that may help you : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7320/problems-installing-force-com-ide

Comment: IS it only working 1.6?

Comment: Yes, or at least to my knowledge. Can't find a reference to that in the force.com ide release notes.

Comment: @Sdry: I changed the question, any idea's?